# Building a CPFP raw transaction to confirm a force-closed Lightning channel

Tags: lightning-network, bitcoin-cli, replace-by-fee, child-pays-for-parent

I am attempting to use bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction to build a CPFP transaction to pay for a low-fee channel close that has been unconfirmed for over a week.

I have all of the details, i.e, txid, output to spend, but as I have not attempted this before, I would like to ensure I am formatting the transaction correctly, including making it BIP 125 replaceable.

If someone who is experienced with this procedure could provide some assistance, I would appreciate a hand.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is a self-help question and answer platform. We only deal in Q&A, posting jobs is not on-topic. Please edit your post to ask about a specific issue you are encountering, then flag your topic for reopening.